# .clang-tidy configuration file content is being ignored

Tags: clang, clang-tidy

I want to modify the checks that the code analyzer program `clang-tidy` is doing, but it seems like the content of the configuration file `.clang-tidy` is being ignored.

1. I create the file by calling `clang-tidy` with the flag `-dump-config` and redirect the output to the file `.clang-tidy`.
2. Then I call `sed` to replace the value `800` with the value `700`, which corresponds to the option with key `google-readability-function-size.StatementThreshold`. The specific option is not important to me, this is just for testing.
3. I verify that the value has indeed been changed.
4. Lastly, I rerun `clang-tidy` to see if it has accepted the new configuration, but it remains unchanged.

```sh
# generate config
clang-tidy -dump-config > .clang-tidy
# change config
sed -i 's/800/700/' .clang-tidy
# verify change
grep '700' .clang-tidy
# use config, does not work
clang-tidy -config '' -dump-config
```

The CheckOption remains at the default value, the content of the config file has been ignored:

```yaml
CheckOptions:
# some lines omitted for brevity
  - key:             google-readability-function-size.StatementThreshold
    value:           '800'
```

Running `clang-tidy -config '' -dump-config -explain-config` shows that the configuration file has at least been found, i.e. many clang-analyzer specific checks are enabled in the detected config file, but the check `google-readability-function-size.StatementThreshold` is not listed.

I also tried passing the config directly as command line parameter  with the command `clang-tidy -config="{CheckOptions: [ {key: google-readability-function-size.StatementThreshold, value: 700} ]}" -dump-config`, but got the same result.

The command `clang-tidy --version` gives the following output, running on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 10.0.0
  
  Optimized build.
  Default target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  Host CPU: haswell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the change, you need to enable the check:

```
Checks:          'google-readability-function-size'
```

You can see it changed in the effective configuration with:

```
clang-tidy --dump-config
```

Another pitfall to be aware of is that errors parsing the values will be silently discarded.